# Установить библиотеку DocX

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно скачать файлы библиотеки DocX (Xceed.Words.NET.dll и WindowsBase.dll)? Установить через диспетчер пакетов Nuget не удается (ошибка "Базовое соединение закрыто: Непредвиденная ошибка при передаче").

Comment: Через VPN попробуйте, скорее всего ошибка из-за блокировок РКН.

Comment: Xceed.Words.NET.dll скачала, но не нашла WindowsBase.dll. Скажите пожалуйста, для работы достаточно добавить в ссылки файл Xceed.Words.NET.dll ?

Comment: WindowsBase.dll это вроде как часть .NET фреймворка

Comment: WindowsBase.dll это часть WPF, если у вас не WPF-проект, подключите ее из References